# Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PlaceholderTextBox' to type 'Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuTextBox'

Tags: c#, winforms, bunifu

I'm trying to convert a bunifu text into a sender in the key down event

```
private void TxtName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        BunifuTextBox textBox = (BunifuTextBox)sender;
    }
```

but im having this error

Comment: *trying to convert a bunifu text into a sender* - Actually, you're trying to cast(subtly different to a convert, in C# terms) a `sender` into a BunifuTextBox, and it isn't a BunifuTextBox; it's a PlaceholderTextBox (and there is no available automatic conversion between the two)

Comment: This means that `BunifuTextBox` doesn't inherit from `PlaceholderTextBox`, so you'll either need to change your Form to have a `BunifuTextBox` in the UI or cast the sender to a `PlaceholderTextBox`. FYI, it's preferred to use [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) so it wont throw an exception when casting to a incompatible type and rather just return null

Comment: Please show the error.